# Concatenate strings in abbrev file

Tags: emacs, elisp

What's the reason by `concatenate` is not working in my abbreviations file? I would like 'env' to expand to this little chunk of code, and for readability reasons I prefer to separate the string into multiple lines. However, the abbreviation seems to be ignored by Emacs.

```
(define-abbrev-table 'python-mode-abbrev-table
  '(
    ("env" (concatenate 'string
             "#! /usr/bin/env python\n"
             "\n"
             "from __future__ import division\n"
             "from __future__ import print_function\n"
             "from __future__ import absolute_import\n"
             "from __future__ import unicode_literals\n\n")
       nil 3)
   ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions are not evaluated inside a quoted list. You can use backquote to selectively evaluate parts of a list structure:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'python-mode-abbrev-table
  `(
    ("env" ,(concatenate 'string
             "#! /usr/bin/env python\n"
             "\n"
             "from __future__ import division\n"
             "from __future__ import print_function\n"
             "from __future__ import absolute_import\n"
             "from __future__ import unicode_literals\n\n")
       nil 3)
))
```

Within a backquoted expression, comma indicates the parts that should be evaluated.

Comment: It might be simpler just to express it as `(list (list "env" (concatenate ...) nil 3))`.

Comment: I'd put this list on the borderline where backquote is needed. But if you usually write a complex list as a quoted literal, it can be easiest to use backquote when you want to tweak a few elements into computed.